# AR Core OnePlus 3T

Tags: oneplus-3

Recently, I reset my `OnePlus 3T` settings. So, after that, it says that my phone doesn't support `AR`. But it worked before and this phone in the list of supported devices.

Ar Core version - `1.9.190422056` - the newest.

Comment: might be silly suggestion.. but did u try installing google arcore https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.ar.core

Answer (score 0):

Just install [ARCore by Google](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.ar.core)

> ARCore is Google's platform for building augmented-reality experiences.

[image]

If it still doesn't work, try first to **restart the phone**. Then if you still have the error message try some alternative AR applications like [Measure](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.tango.measure).

Answer (score 0):

So, as I investigated - `OnePlus 3T` just is not supported in version `1.9`, so I deleted `ArCore` apk-file and in my dependencies in `Gradle` set `1.8` version. After that installed version `1.8`  of `ArCore`